# how to deploy app if i dont have nodejs in root folder

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, web, deployment

Im going to deploy my first project to see how it works, but everywhere and everyone use `npm run build` from root package.json. I have set backend and frontend separate in root folder.
What should i do

- `npm run build` from backend and try to access to client to install dependencies?
- install node in root folder and install all dependencies from backend?

Here is the folder

[image: project directory]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to hassle with such efforts. A lot of people use single folder where they have both `backend` and `frontend` in separate folder. Instead of thinking that they are in same root folder,think of it this way, backend and frontend are in different folders and they both have individual package.json files that are completely isolated from each other. So creating a build wouldn't be an issue for backend and frontend separately.

There is only one gitlab-ci.yml file is in the root folder. What you can do is create a **path** in the yaml file, such that it goes one folder down to take the build from frontend and backend, and deploy it to their respective environments.

Below is an attached image for the deployment workflow of github actions. The client folder contains the `react` code, while the server contains the `express` code for apis. I have created different jobs for the builds to be created and deployed. The yaml file guides the github actions to take the code from the context route and push it to the image on the docker server. You can make the same changes for the gitlab in the yaml file.

[image: github actions yaml file]